# How can I cache WordPress Rest API Response

Tags: api, cache, json, rest-api

I'm using WordPress rest API for developing my Android application. But I can not cache the response.

How can I add required headers to REST API response so that my app can save the response for offline reading?

Comment: what caching of any kind have to do with offline reading? if you need to store a response in your app, just store it.

Comment: I'm using Volley which will automatically cache the response. But I it is not caching only WP rest API response. Do I need to add any headers to say volley to cache them?

Comment: no idea what is volley ;) just doesn't sound right that caching info in an app depends on headers sent by the server. You can write a plugin to set headers on specific request, just sounds weird.

Comment: Caching in the application depends on the headers of response we received. Read this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers

I'm not a server guy and I don't know the exact terms to describe it.

Comment: you can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-cache/

Answer (score 6):

You should create a new instance from `WP_REST_Response` to set the `Cache-Control` value.

```
<?php
register_rest_route('wp/v2', '/your_endpoint', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'function_callback',
));

function function_callback($data) {
  $response = array(
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
  );

  $result = new WP_REST_Response($response, 200);

  // Set headers.
  $result->set_headers(array('Cache-Control' => 'max-age=3600'));

  return $result;
}
```

[Click here](https://www.kennethlange.com/boost-your-rest-api-with-http-caching/) to get more info about directives.

Comment: If the response is different depending on the $data that gets requested, will the $response that gets cached be specific to that $data, or would it just return the same cached response from previous requests?

Comment: Will return the new response.